# Memory Limit Exceed in C dynamic array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I am trying to create a 3D array using memory allocation, and free it. However, it seems that my program exceed the memory limit. How can I optimize it? And what point do i miss?

function.h

```
unsigned*** new_3d_array(unsigned n,unsigned m,unsigned k);
void delete_3d_array(unsigned ***arr);

unsigned*** new_3d_array(unsigned n,unsigned m,unsigned k){
    unsigned*** array = (unsigned***)malloc(n * sizeof(unsigned**));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            array[i] = (unsigned**)malloc(m * sizeof(unsigned*));
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    array[i][j] = (unsigned*)malloc(k * sizeof(unsigned));
            }
    }

    return array;
}

void delete_3d_array(unsigned ***arr){
    unsigned long long int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //Get individual general size
    unsigned long long int m = sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                 free(arr[i][j]);
            }
            free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"function.h"

//Sample Input
//60 100 100 100 7122

unsigned random_seed=7122;
unsigned Random(){
    return random_seed=random_seed*0xdefaced+1;
}
int main(){
    int n,m,k,_;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%u",&_,&n,&m,&k,&random_seed);
    while(_--){
        unsigned ***arr=new_3d_array(n,m,k);
        int i,j,l;
        for(i=0;i<n;++i){
            for(j=0;j<m;++j){
                for(l=0;l<k;++l){
                    arr[i][j][l]=Random();
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;++i){
            unsigned a,b,c;
            a=Random()%n;
            b=Random()%m;
            c=Random()%k;
            if(i)putchar(' ');
            printf("%u",arr[a][b][c]);
        }
        puts("");
        delete_3d_array(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to define it using for loop. Because the free function only pass the 3d array as argument, I can only find the size by dividing it.

Turned my program is not optimized enough.

Comment: Bugs here: `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-pointing-to-the-first-element-a Does it crash during free()?

Comment: In the real world, for a "full" `m*n*k` "brick" people usually allocate a single `m*n*k*`-sized array, and index into it as `[x+y*m+z*m*n]` (where 0<=x<m, 0<=y<n, 0<=z<k).

Comment: @Lundin the program compiled perfectly, but MLE. I also have suspicions on that part, is there any way to parse n, m, k to the delete function, without adding arguments?

Comment: @tevemadar I prefer to allocate it as a `[x][y][z]` array and index it as `[i][j][k]` but maybe that's too readable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend to ditch the pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer and instead allocate this all as a fast contiguous 3D array instead. [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

> Because the free function only pass the 3d array as argument, I can only find the size by dividing it.

No, you can't do that. There is no information stored anywhere regarding the size of the arrays, it is the programmer's job to keep track of that. `sizeof` is mostly a compile-time operator so it has no magical knowledge of how large some dynamic arrays are. What you get instead is the size in bytes of the *pointers*. For details see [How to find the size of an array (from a pointer pointing to the first element array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-pointing-to-the-first-element-a).

So you need to declare `delete_3d_array` with 3 size parameters. Notably this wouldn't have been a problem if you had used a 3D array instead, then you could just `free(array)` on a single line.

Quick fix (not tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned random_seed=7122;
unsigned Random(){
    return random_seed=random_seed*0xdefaced+1;
}
int main(){
    int x,y,z,_;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%u",&_,&x,&y,&z,&random_seed);
    if(x==0 || y==0 || z==0)
        return 1;

    while(_--){
        unsigned (*arr)[y][z] = malloc( sizeof(unsigned[x][y][z]) );
        if(arr == NULL)
            return 1;

        for(int i=0;i<x;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<y;++j){
                for(int k=0;k<z;++k){
                    arr[i][j][k]=Random();
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
            unsigned a,b,c;
            a=Random()%x;
            b=Random()%y;
            c=Random()%z;
            if(i)putchar(' ');
            printf("%u",arr[a][b][c]);
        }
        puts("");
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for providing me with a wonderful reference. I will share this information with my colleague.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have 3d array only arrays of pointers.
2. When you pass the pointer you can't get the size of the array as `sizeof` will give you only the size of the pointer, not the referenced object
3. Use array pointers
4. Do not use `_` as variable name. It does not look "hacky"
5. Use more meaningful variable names.

```
void *new_3d_array(size_t arrs,  size_t rows,size_t cols, unsigned long long (**array)[rows][cols])
{
    *array = malloc(arrs * sizeof(**array));
    return *array;
}

void delete_3d_array(void *arr)
{
    free(arr);
}

unsigned random_seed=7122;
unsigned Random(){
    return random_seed=random_seed*0xdefaced+1;
}
int main(){
    size_t arrs,rows,cols,flag;
    scanf("%zu%zu%zu%zu%u",&flag,&arrs,&rows,&cols,&random_seed);
    while(flag--){
        unsigned long long (*arr)[rows][cols];
        if(!new_3d_array(arrs,rows,cols,&arr)) {/* handle error */}
        
        size_t i,j,l;
        for(i=0;i<arrs;++i){
            for(j=0;j<rows;++j){
                for(l=0;l<cols;++l){
                    arr[i][j][l]=Random();
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<5;++i){
            unsigned a,b,c;
            a=Random()%arrs;
            b=Random()%rows;
            c=Random()%cols;
            if(i)putchar(' ');
            printf("%llu",arr[a][b][c]);
        }
        puts("");
        delete_3d_array(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ozh7evh8h

Comment: You redefine `i`

Comment: @stark where? I do not see it. I changed some variable names to be more meaningful